# How to use MPlayerCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, media-player, playlist, mplayer

I'm doing a school project regarding making a media player. I'm doing this with python and `wxPython` as my GUI and MPlayerCtrl as my library to control all my button. However I'm having problem using MPlayerCtrl. I can't seem to get the function inside the MPlayerCtrl to work.

I am able to get the media playing but when I try to use the function `"self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()"`, it's returning me with "none" which is nothing. I've also tried with other function inside MPlayerCtrl and still having the same problem. Can anyone advise me on what i am doing wrong?

## A portion of the code:

---

```
def on_add_file(self, event):
    """
    Add a Movie and start playing it
    """
    wildcard = "Media Files (*.*)|*.*"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultDir=self.currentFolder, 
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        self.currentFolder = os.path.dirname(path[0])
        trackPath = '"%s"' % path.replace("\\", "/")
        self.mplayer.Loadfile(trackPath)

        t_len = self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()
        print t_len
        #self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
        #self.playbackTimer.Start(100)
```

---

Reference: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've copied this example from [**here**](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player). I had the same problem with it. From [**this forum**](http://www.python-forum.de/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=28137&start=15) (German) I found that you should only call `GetTimeLength()` after the `EVT_MEDIA_STARTED` has fired. For your example, move:

```
    t_len = self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()
    self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
    self.playbackTimer.Start(100)
```

`from on_add_file()` to `on_media_started()`, and at the end of `on_add_file()`, put:

```
    self.playbackTimer.Start()
    self.mplayer.Start()
```